# How to disable Spring Java Reconcile notification in STS 4.19.1

Tags: spring-tool-suite, reconcile

Whenever I'm working on the STS, a little window appears referring to Spring Java Reconcile.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etF5U.png)

How do I disable this? I already looked for it here in the IDE, but I didn't find it.

I already went to Preferences to look for it, but I didn't find it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzpD9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found this option, checked it, and restarted Eclipse.
The message is no longer displayed.

[image]